# making inventory movement report using sql query

Tags: c#, sql

[image: check this picture]

---

I have three tables in the above picture. I want to get the Inventory movement report (table 3), which I do with the code below:

```
SELECT * FROM   
(
    select  1 as 'Factor', Products_Data.ItemCost, Products_Data.Type as 'ItemType'  
        , TBL_ItemsMovement.StorageID,  Products_Data.ID 
        , Products_Data.BarCode , Products_Data.Product_Name , Products_Data.Main_Unit ,TBL_ItemsMovement.Type 
        , Products_Data.Sub_Category
        ,  (SELECT SUM((Incoming -Outgoing) * Factor)  
            FROM TBL_ItemsMovement op 
            WHERE op.ItemID = Products_Data.ID AND op.StorageID in (" + cmbstorage.EditValue.ToString() + @") 
                AND op.Insertion_Date <  CONVERT(datetime, '" + strdate.DateTime.ToString(Program.DateFormat) + @"')  
         ) as 'opening'
        ,sum((Incoming -Outgoing) * Factor) as 'Qty'  ,
        (SELECT SUM( Inventory.Qty) 
         FROM Inventory 
         WHERE Inventory.Storage_Code in (" + cmbstorage.EditValue.ToString() + @") 
             AND Inventory.ID  = Products_Data.ID
         )  as 'CurrentQty'
        , (SELECT SUM((Incoming -Outgoing) * Factor)  
           FROM TBL_ItemsMovement op 
           WHERE op.ItemID = Products_Data.ID AND op.StorageID in (" + cmbstorage.EditValue.ToString() + @") 
               AND op.Insertion_Date <  CONVERT(datetime, '" + endate.DateTime.ToString(Program.DateFormat) + @"')  
        ) as 'closed' 
    from Products_Data
    left join TBL_ItemsMovement on Products_Data.ID = TBL_ItemsMovement.ItemID 
        and TBL_ItemsMovement.StorageID in (" + cmbstorage.EditValue.ToString() + ")
        and TBL_ItemsMovement.Insertion_Date between CONVERT(datetime,  '" + strdate.DateTime.ToString(Program.DateFormat) + "'  )  and  CONVERT(datetime,  '" + endate.DateTime.ToString(Program.DateFormat) + @"') 
    where  Products_Data.Type  < 4 and isdeleted = 0 
    group by Products_Data.ID ,TBL_ItemsMovement.StorageID
        ,TBL_ItemsMovement.ItemID,  Products_Data.BarCode
        , Products_Data.Product_Name,  Products_Data.Main_Unit 
        ,TBL_ItemsMovement.Type, Products_Data.Sub_Category 
        , Products_Data.Type   , TBL_ItemsMovement.StorageID
        , Products_Data.ItemCost

) t 
PIVOT (
    SUM(Qty) 
    FOR Type IN (
        [0], 
        [1], 
        [2], 
        [3], 
        [4], 
        [8], 
        [9], 
        [10],
        [11],
        [12],
        [24]
    )
) AS pivot_table;
```

This query takes too long to execute. How can I make it faster?

Comment: I do not see the relationship between the SQL Query posted and the picture.  Which table is the SQL producing?  The picture is probably coming from a RDLC report and not the SQL you posted.

Comment: Fix your query formatting.  Do you think anyone will read that???

Comment: Images are **NOT** the accepted way to share sample data here. No one is going to be able to read that, and you're unlikely to get much help until its fixed (because your question really is _broken_ as it is).

Answer (score 0):

Performance issues can have various different root causes. That's why I will focus on suggestions about some obvious aspects of the query that I find worthy of improving.

**Use Sql-Parameters instead of dynamic Sql**

Injecting values into a statement rather than using parameterized queries can degrade execution performance. Rather than generating a query plan once and then reusing it over again, Sql Server might generate a new query plan for every execution of the query.
I think your query could even be turned into a table-valued function. Which would make it easier for you to write, test and optimize it.
[Here is some further documentation on parameterized queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/using-parameterized-queries-with-the-sqldatasource-cs)

**Replace subqueries in columns with cross apply / outer apply**

The inline view within your query has 3 columns which contain a subquery.
One of them is the following:

```
,(SELECT sum(Inventory.Qty)
FROM Inventory
WHERE Inventory.Storage_Code IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@CmbStorage, ','))
    AND Inventory.ID = Products_Data.ID
) AS 'CurrentQty'
```

You can gain performance by moving this subquery into an apply-clause:

```
OUTER APPLY (
SELECT sum(Inventory.Qty)
FROM Inventory
WHERE Inventory.Storage_Code IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@CmbStorage, ','))
    AND Inventory.ID = Products_Data.ID
) Current(CurrentQty)
```

You can then put Current.CurrentQty in the column list to ouput the value.
Please note that this approach can lead to null values if the query result is empty. Also note that I have replaced the injected comma seperated string with a parameter that is turned into a table using the string_split function.

**Analyze the execution plan of your query**

Use Sql Server Management Studio to [analyze the query execution plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-the-estimated-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver16). It will show you how expensive each operation during query execution is. That will give you an idea on where to put further optimization efforts.

**Disclaimer**

I must admit that i did not try to understand every last aspect of this query. But I think have I good idea on what it's supposed to do though. Missing indexes may be a major reason for performance issues. But without any further information on that it is hard to give any specific advice.
I still hope that my suggestions will help you make some improvements.